# NetBeans - permission denied

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, sudo, permission-denied

Im trying to save a simple script in netbeans to htdocs, but i only get permission denied, is there anyway to give netbeans full permission like you do with other programs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure the `htdocs` folder has WRITE (**Read & Write**) permissions on.

- Either go, via Finder, to the folder, **Get Info** and - at the lower part - **Sharing & Permissions**
- Or, goto the `htdocs` folder from the terminal and do :

  `sudo chmod 777 -R htdocs`